# MySQL: How to migrate tables while preserving relationship?

Tags: mysql, database-migration

I have several tables related to each other with foreign keys. Each table has a primary key with autoincrement. There are some thousand rows in each table.

Here are my tables:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
    val INT
);
CREATE TABLE table2 (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
    val INT, 
    table1_id INT REFERENCES table1 (id)
);
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (1,1), (2,2), (3,3);
INSERT INTO table2 VALUES (1,1,1), (2,2,2), (3,3,3);
```

I need to add all data to another database where the tables already exist (with the same definition) and have some data in it. The existing data must be preserved.

How to export and reimport these tables while preserving relationship between these tables?

My idea was to write a program to export the tables into a JSON and another progam to do the reimport by inserting the rows an adjusting the foreign keys (I mainly use PHP). or should I use Microsoft Excel? But I suppose there are simpler ways to go.

Comment: Should the keys change? Then you need to write some application to handle this, as I don't think there are tools that would automatically resolve depending entities for you

Comment: The keys can change, but the relationship of the rows must be preserved.

Comment: @Akina yes. I updated my question.

Comment: Does the data to be imported may cause unique or some another constraint violations (except PKs)? If both databases contains the same row - does these rows may be combined into one row?

Comment: @Akina The imported data has to be added.

Comment: @Akina The import has to be done on a different MySQL server.

Comment: If your database is exactly the same, i think mysql has a function export with all data or you can look plsql to do this and extract in one or more files sql .

Comment: @Akina Yes, just adding is required. No similarity checks must be done.

Comment: @Akina FEDERATED feature is not supported.

Comment: I would export the data from the tables (SELECT .. INTO OUTFILE), moved the files to the destination server, where it imported the data into temporary tables (LOAD DATA INFILE) and then moved it to work tables using a stored procedure.

Comment: @SebastienTernisien The standard export/import function does not change keys :-(   and PL/SQL does not wok in MySQL

Comment: @Akina Does LOAD DATA INFILE adjust foreign keys?

Comment: No of course. You would adjust references programmatically during copying the data from temporary tables to working tables.

Comment: The answer of @Akina is the solution to do your job with some rework during the extraction.

Answer (score 1):

An example.

> ```
> -- working tables with data
> CREATE TABLE main_w (id_m INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
>                      val INT);
> CREATE TABLE slave_w (id_s INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
>                       val INT, 
>                       id_m INT REFERENCES main_w (id_m));
> INSERT INTO main_w VALUES (1,1), (2,2), (3,3);
> INSERT INTO slave_w VALUES (1,1,1), (2,2,2), (3,3,3);
> ```

> ```
> -- temporary tables with data to be added
> CREATE TABLE main_s (id_m INT, 
>                      val INT);
> CREATE TABLE slave_s (id_s INT, 
>                       val INT, 
>                       id_m INT);
> INSERT INTO main_s VALUES (1,11), (2,22), (3,33);
> INSERT INTO slave_s VALUES (1,11,1), (2,22,2), (3,33,3);
> ```

> ```
> -- add data from temporary main to working main
> INSERT INTO main_w
> SELECT NULL, val 
> FROM main_s;
> ```

> ```
> -- add data from temporary slave to working slave adjusting references
> INSERT INTO slave_w
> SELECT NULL, slave_s.val, main_w.id_m
> FROM slave_s
> JOIN main_s ON slave_s.id_m = main_s.id_m
> JOIN main_w ON main_s.val = main_w.val;
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7f9c4522bb287e6916133663306d6889)*

Comment: Ok, I understand the principle, but looks not as an easy-to-go-solution. Before I go deeper here, where do I have to execute these statements? On the import side?

Comment: @WeSee *where do I have to execute these statements? On the import side?* Yes, after the data is loaded (LOAD DATA INFILE) into temporary tables.